# Обновление в форме опций (в input select) по ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Не получается обновить список опций в select после добавления новой категории.

Есть форма:

```
    <form id ="add_category" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Название</label>
    <input type="text" class="uk-input" name="name" id="name" required>

    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Родительская</label>
    <select name="parrent" class="uk-select" id="parrent">
        <option value="" selected>Без родительской</option>
        <div id="addresult_category_list"><?include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/updates/category_list_admin.php";?></div>
    </select>

    <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Сортировка</label>
    <input type="number" class="uk-input" name="sort" id="sort" required>

    <div class="uk-margin">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Добавить категорию" id="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-default">
    
    </div>
```

В неё подгружаются опции из файла category_list_admin.php его содержимое:

```
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE parrent=''";
            if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ 
                foreach($result as $row){ 
                $category = $row["name"]; 
                $category_id = $row["id"];
                echo "<option value=\"$category_id\">$category</option>";
            } 
            } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}
```

На странице с формой добавляю скрипт, чтобы после добавления новой категории без перезагрузки страницы в форме появлялись новые опции, но почему-то не работает. Опции в форме не обновляются.

```
<script>
$("#add_category").submit(function(updatelist){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/updates/category_list_admin.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData:false,
      success: function(html){  
        $("#addresult_category_list").html(html);
      }  
    });
});
```

Если я сделаю пустой див (вне формы)

```
<div id="addresult_category_list2"></div>
```

и направлю туда ответ аякса

```
   <script>
    $("#add_category").submit(function(updatelist){
        updatelist.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/updates/category_list_admin.php',
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: false,
          cache: false,
          processData:false,
          success: function(html){  
            $("#addresult_category_list2").html(html);
          }  
        });
    });
</script>
```

то после добавления новой категории, в новом диве корректно отобразится весь список категорий. Почему это не работает в форме с опциями я не понимаю.

Comment: Как не работает: наступает ночь? Взрывается компьютер? На странице выводятся слова матом?

Comment: @u_mulder забастовка

Comment: список опций не обновляется

Comment: так ты впихиваешь данные в div а не в option

Comment: так я впихиваю опции через обработчик в div: `echo "<option value=\"$category_id\">$category</option>";`

Comment: первый же echo возвращает контент и успокаивается.....надо накапливать данные и скопом их отправлять....просто на будущее (и на текущее)

Comment: извините, не очень понятно, а как решить это в моей задаче? По идее весь контент в этом диве после срабатывания скрипта должен обновиться и показать все опции, включая новые. Что значит успокаивается?

Comment: ты в первом же echo отдал контент на клиент...всё. скрипт отработал...... как решить: написано комментом же выше

Comment: так echo в foreach находится как он может отдавать только первое echo если их там несколько

Comment: echo - вывод в output (читай как ответ).  ajax дожидается ответа сервера......понимаешь?

Comment: а понимаю, что ajax посылает запрос в обработчик, где получает ответ со списком всех опций и заменяет эти данные в div. Если я сделаю пустой див (вне формы) и направлю туда ответ аякса, то после добавления новой категории, в новом диве корректно отобразится весь список категорий. Почему это не работает в форме  с опциями я не понимаю.

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что в select можно вставлять  div и что это крректно?

Comment: Это же работает при первой загрузке страницы `<div id="addresult_category_list"><?include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/updates/category_list_admin.php";?></div>` и работает корректно

Comment: В select нельзя div класть, браузер автоматически удаляет его оттуда, добавляйте option напрямую в select.
Рекомендую использовать валидатор для проверки html-страниц, тогда можно будет избежать таких ошибок https://validator.w3.org

Comment: @pgood действительно удаляет, а есть идея как сделать так чтобы новые опции через аякс добавлялись?

Comment: Точно также как в div: $("#parrent").html('<option value="">Без родительской</option>' + html);

Comment: Еще можно обрезать длину массива опций у селекта до одного: $("#parrent").get(0).options.length = 1; так останется только первый option, а потом добавляем полученный аяксом HTML-код $("#parrent").html($("#parrent").html() + html);